# Is it okay to define a foreign key referencing a ‘user_id’ column from every table?

Tags: mysql, database-design, schema

I have a multi user site which in which

- a `user` can have many `restaurants`,
- each `restaurant` can have many `menus` and
- each `menu` can have many `items`.

For security purposes, I was going to add a `user_id` foreign key making a reference to the `user.user_id` column from each of the pertinent tables. That way, when updating the data, I can use the `id` of the row they are updating in combination with their `user_id` (stored in a session at the application program level) to ensure they don't maliciously update or view another `users` content.

**Questions**

- Is this a common practice?
- Is it still *normalized* to do this?

**Responses to comments**

The code is only running on a website I control. But I want to prevent a `user` from accessing a row of data that he/she does not own, based on his/her `user_id` value. For instance, at the application program level, if they send a GET request to `/menus/1` it will retrieve the row from the `menu` table with the `id` value of *1*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your first question, I've managed *many* systems that do this. Some actually defined that Foreign Key relationship. Others had the "foreign key" field, but didn't define it in the database as key. This led to interesting quirks like data loaded outside of the application (pre-populated rows) having "updated by" fields with values that weren't users in the user table. Typically the tables had "ChangedBy" columns that stored User IDs and "ChangedOn" fields that stored a date/time for the change event.

For your second, why *wouldn't* it be normalized, if you set up the Foreign Key relationship back to a users table? You aren't duplicating the user information at the menu, restaurant, etc. tables, right? Just the foreign key ID field.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the type of authentication you are doing. A common practice in SQL Server is to use only windows authentication, then to use SUSER_SNAME() as the default when saving to a User_ID column. I am not certain which MySQL equivalent is correct, but based on a quick Google it is likely either

```
CURRENT_USER
USER()
```

Then you can check the value saved in the table against the value for the person changing the record.

And no, this does not break database normalization. As a practice it is quite common to include metadata like AddTime, AddUserID, LastChangeTime, LastChangeUserID. In fact in some environments I have worked in, it was a requirement that all tables have these columns for audit-ability.